# How to distribute GridFS fs.chunks in MongoDB Shared Cluster

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have a MongoDB sharded/replicated cluster with ten shards.  I did a bulk ingest to this cluster about ten days ago, and it has a pretty significant amount of data in GridFS.  Per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#sharding-gridfs), I created a shard index on `{ files_id : 1, n : 1 }`.

As you can see in the graphic below, the distribution of data in the shards is very uneven.  The balancer is enabled, but it still looks like this.  (This is just a chart of the output of `db.fs.chunks.getShardDistribution()`.)

How do I force this to rebalance?  Do I remove shard s9?  Do I [manually split chunks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/split-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)?  I don't see any "jumbo" shards listed in `sh.status(true)`.

Also - How do I prevent this from happening in the future with the index listed in the documentation?

[image: shard distribution]

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have chosen the autogenerated ID as the shard key which typically produces the behavior you are seeing. Read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys). Use a hashed shard key or shard on a different key.

Comment: The docs and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190388/gridfs-why-cant-i-shard-chunks-with-a-hashed-key) indicate I can’t use hash shard keys.

Comment: Provide your own id then?